# Converting Observable to Promise to return data to grid

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, devextreme

I have a service that returns an Observable, which I convert to a Promise and look to map to a store that will show data to grid.

**Service to get summary details**

```
getSummaries(year: String): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.get(this.appUrl + '/summary?year=' + year, {headers: this.headers});
  }
```

I have the below component that calls the service to return details that I expect to populate in a grid. My grid is currently empty and does not show any details from the service.

**Component**

```
  export class AppComponent {
    dataSource: any;

   constructor(myService: SummaryService) {
    this.dataSource = {
          load: (loadOptions: any) => {
      return myService.getSummary(this.selectedYear)
        .toPromise()
        .then(details => { this.Summaries =  details.json()})
        .catch(error => { this.msgService.showError(this.msgs, "Error while getting Summary for year " + this.selectedYear )})
},
      fields: [{
        caption: 'Month End',
        width: 120,
        dataField: 'monthEndDate',
        area: 'row'
      },{
        caption: 'Company',
        dataField: 'company',
        width: 150,
        area: 'row'    
      }, {
        caption: 'Department',
        dataField: 'department',
        width: 150,
        area: 'row'
      }, {
        caption: 'Location',
        dataField: 'location',
        width: 150,
        area: 'row'
      }, {
        caption: 'Commodity',
        dataField: 'commodity',
        width: 150,
        area: 'row'
      },{
        caption: 'Inventory',
        dataField: 'inventoryCount',
        dataType: 'number',
        summaryType: 'sum',
        format: 'decimal',
        area: 'data',
        width: 100
      },{
        caption: 'Breaks',
        dataField: 'breakCount',
        dataType: 'number',
        summaryType: 'sum',
        format: 'decimal',
        area: 'data',
        width: 100
      },{
        caption: 'Approved',
        dataField: 'approvedCount',
        dataType: 'number',
        summaryType: 'sum',
        format: 'decimal',
        area: 'data',
        width: 100,
      }],
      store: this.summaries
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't have any handlers registered in the Promise `then()` method.

Comment: I updated the main thread with the load option with then handler but that did not work either

Comment: post the code where you consume the data

Comment: Please see the load function (pasted here and in my original code above) where I look to consume from the service.    load: (loadOptions: any) => {
      return myService.getSummaries(this.selectedYear)
        .map(details => { this.summaries =  details.json()  })
        .toPromise()
        .catch(error => { this.msgService.showError(this.msgs, "Error while getting Summary for year " + this.selectedYear )})
        },

Comment: You are still returning the Promise instead of data, is that what you want? post the code where you call this `load` function